# Suppose $f$ is integrable and $\int_{a}^{x} f = 0,\ \forall x \in [a,b]$ then $f = 0$ almost everywhere.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I was proving this theorem of Measure theory -

"Suppose $f$ is integrable and $\int_{a}^{x} f = 0 \forall x \in [a,b]$ then $f = 0$ almost everywhere."

Here is what I tried in the proof here -

Let us consider set $E =\{ x | f(x) > 0\}$ is of non-zero measure.

$E$ is measurable as $f^{-1}(0,\infty)$ is measurable , applying one of the characterizations of measurable sets , states that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there is a closed set $F \subset E$ suchthat $m(E|F) < \epsilon$ and $m(F) \neq 0$.

so $[a,b]/F$ is open let us denote it by $O$.and it can be expressed as a countable disjoint union of open sets so $O =\cup_{n \geq 1} (a_{n},b_{n})$.

Now $\int_{a}^{b}f = 0$ as it will be true for $x = b$

$\int_{F}f + \int_{O}f = 0$
$\implies \int_{O}f \neq 0$

So,$\int_{\cup_{(a_{n},b_{n})}}f = \sum_{n \geq 1}\int_{(a_{n},b_{n})}f \neq0 $

Implying there exist $N$ such that $\int_{(a_{N},b_{N})}f \neq 0$
$\int_{a}^{b_{N}}f - \int_{a}^{a_{N}}f \neq 0$

$\implies \int_{a}^{b_{N}}f \neq 0 $ or $\int_{a}^{a_{N}}f \neq 0$ 
Which is a contradiction as to our integral $\int_{a}^{x}f = 0 \forall x \in [a,b]$ .

Now we conclude due to the contradiction that $E$ is a set of zero measure and I think that similar can be done for $f < 0$ ,

now how do I proceed in order to show that $f = 0$ almost everywhere

Any help is great!

,[almost everywhere part is proved above I think by proving that set of points where $f\neq 0$ is of measure zero.]

Comment: Are you sure that this is true? The function $\chi_{[a-1,a]}+\chi_{[b,b+1]}$ is integrable, non-zero and has a zero integral over $[a,x]$ for $x \in [a,b]$ (where  $\chi_A$ is the indicator function for the set $A$)

Comment: Yes that seems also true but this is a standard theorem.Is this the almost everywhere part?

Comment: I think you want to prove that f is 0 on [a,b]? On any other domain you can just construct a function which is zero on that interval and non-zero elsewhere.

Comment: If you are trying to prove that $f = 0$ a.e, on $[a,b]$, then the above proof is sufficient, since $[a,b] = \{ x | f(x) < 0\} \cup \{ x | f(x) > 0\} \cup \{ x | f(x) = 0\}$, so this shows that $\{ x | f(x) = 0\} $ has same measure as $[a,b]$ (since the union is disjoint). Hence, you are done.

Comment: Yes,that is nice but how can we show that $f=0$ a.e. that is even outside $[a,b]$? @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: No, it's not true outside $[a,b]$, as has been pointed out.

Comment: Yes,I think in the first comment only $\chi_{[a-1,a]}$ would be enough ?@BernardWojcik